# Overloaded [] operator for hash table to a vector

Tags: c++, oop, vector, operator-overloading, hashtable

I am working on a simple hash table in C++. I have methods to insert, delete, and search the hash table for the specified key. I know that the C++ map STL container can handle my situation, but I would kind of like to code my own as an educational exercise.

Basically I have a hash table that will take a single string and map it to a vector of other strings. This is easy to do in a method because calling a .Add() or .Delete() will behave as expected. I would however like to create an overloaded [] operator to the class that is able to do these operations on the vector.

For example, if I want to add an item to the vector I can write something like this:

```
     hashTable[string1] = newString;
```

This will set the new string as a member of my vector. The same can be said for delete and search.

```
    hashTable[string1] = "";
    cout << hashTable[string1] << endl;
```

My major problem is that I do not know how to overload the `[]` operator to gain this functionality. I have this function coded up right now. It works on a basic 1 to 1 string match, but not on a string to vector match.

```
    //Return a reference to a vector to update then reassign?

        vector& HashClass::operator[](const string index)
        {
           assert(size >= 0 && size < maxSize); 
           Hash(key);
           return hashTable[index];     
        }
```

I think I'm most stuck on the idea of having a vector return that later needs to be assigned. As the user, I would find this kludgy.

Comment: I personally didn't understand where the problem is... (could just be me though)

Comment: Do you want 2 different return types? One overloaded operator[] returns a string and the other overload returns a vector<string>?

Comment: From what you write it is not clear whether you have one or many strings for each key.

Answer (score 2):

This question is closely related to another question: what behavior do
you want when you access a non-existant value other than in an
assignment?  In other words, what do you want to happen when you write:

```
std::cout << hashTable[string] << std::endl;
```

and `string` is not present in the table?

There are two possible approaches: you can consider it an error, and
throw an exception, or abort, or something similar; or you can return
some sort of default, built with the default constructor, or provided by
the client earlier.

The standard map and unordered_map take the second approach, using the
default constructor to construct a new value.  This allows a very simple
solution: if `operator[]` isn't present, you insert it, initializing it
with the default value.  Then you return a reference to it;
`hashTable[string] = newString;` assigns through the reference to an
already existing value.

In many use cases, the first approach will be preferable (perhaps with a
`contains` function, so you can test up front whether the `operator[]`
will find something or not).  To implement the first approach, you must
first implement specific functions for each type of access:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
class HashTable
{
public:
    Value* get( Key const& key ) const;
    void set( Key const& key, Value const& value );
};
```

(I generally make these public; there's no reason to forbid their use by
a client.)

Then, you define `operator[]` to return a proxy, as follows:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
class HashTable
{
public:
    class Proxy
    {
        HashTable* myOwner;
        Key myKey;
    public:
        Proxy( HashTable* owner, Key const& key )
            : myOwner( owner )
            , myKey( key )
        {
        }

        operator Value const&() const
        {
            Value const* result = myOwner->get( myKey );
            if ( result == NULL ) {
                //  Desired error behavior here...
            }
            return *result;
        }

        Proxy const& operator==( Value const& value ) const
        {
            myOwner->set( myKey, value );
            return *this;
        }
    };

    Value* get( Key const& key ) const;
    void set( Key const& key, Value const& value );

    Proxy operator[]( Key const& key )
    {
        return Proxy( this, key );
    }
};
```

Thus, when you write:

```
hashTable[key] = newString;
```

, the proxy's `operator=` will call `hashTable.put( key, newString )`;
in other contexts, however, it will call the implicit type conversion on
the proxy, which calls `hashTable.get( key )`.

In some cases, even if you desire to return a default value, it may be
preferable to use this solution: the `get` function is not required to
insert anything into the hash table, so the table doesn't fill up with
all of the misses, and you can overload the `operator[]` on `const`, so
you can use it on a `const` hash table as well.  Also, it doesn't
require the value type to have a default constructor.

It does have one disadvantage with respect to the solution used in the
standard; since you can't overload `operator.`, you can't make the proxy
behave like a reference, and things like:

```
hashTable[string].someFunction();
```

don't work.  A work-around is to overload `operator->` in the proxy, but
this leads to a somewhat unnatural syntax:

```
hashTable[string]->someFunction();  //  But the hash table contains
                                    //  values, not pointers!!!
```

(Don't be mislead by the implicit conversion to a reference.  An
implicit conversion will not be considered for `a` in an expression
`a.b`.)

Answer (score 0):

In C++, `[]` access to associative containers is generally given the semantics of default-constructing an object of the mapped type, inserting it with the key, and returning a reference to the inserted mapped object.

So your `operator[]` would be implemented as:

```
    string& HashClass::operator[](const string index)
    {
       assert(size >= 0 && size < maxSize); 
       Hash(key);
       vector &v = hashTable[index];     
       if (index in v) {
          ...
       } else {
          v.push_back(string());
          return v.back();
       }
    }
```